# play multiple sources at once, each from a different position

Tags: gstreamer, video-processing, seek

I would like to use gstreamer to play multiple sources (for instance two video files) simultaneously using a single pipeline but each video starting from a different position, for instance first video from the beginning and the second from the middle. Could someone guide me on how to achieve it?

Simplifying, my pipeline is an equivalent of:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
uridecodebin uri=file:///Users/tmikolaj/Downloads/videoalpha_video_dancer1.webm ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
uridecodebin uri=file:///Users/tmikolaj/Downloads/videoalpha_video_dancer1.webm ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

, but created programmatically.

Obviously, simple seeking the pipeline seeks two files at once.
I was trying to register a probe of the `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_EVENT_UPSTREAM` type from inside the `pad-added` signal callback of the `uridecodebin` element. Inside the probe I wanted to catch the `GST_EVENT_SEEK` event and drop it for the first video. However, it seems that dropping the SEEK message leaves pipeline in a `PAUSED` state and even an explicit state change to `PLAYING` does nothing.
Does anybody has some hints on how to solve that problem?